# "Record and play" tools or "Code/script based" tools?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, ranorex

I am new in test automation.

We are going to plan to start test automation for our platforms (iOS, Android and Web).
I should decide between **"Record and Play"** tools (eg. Ranorex) or **"Code/script based"** tools (eg. Selenium) with C# programming.

I have already tried both Ranorex and Selenium, but I cannot decide which tools should I choose.

I would be so grateful, if you could help me to choose the right tools.

Answer (score 1):

Recored and play for e.g. `SELENIUM IDE` .

**Disadvantage :**

1. Works in Mozilla only.
2. No object orientation.

**Advantage :**

1. Record and play option.
2. Does not require server to start testing.
3. It has UI.
4. Core engine is Javascript based.

for this **Code/script based** we have **Selenium webdriver**.

**Advantage :**

1. Support for multi browser.
2. API's are entirely object oriented.
3. Interacts natively with browser applications.
4. Does not require server to start testing.

**Disadvantage :**

1. Does not support record and playback and has No UI.

**Conclusion :**

It depends on your team, budget, software, and there are n number of factors, but My preference has been code, since once you've the code written you can run that code on **multiple browser** and on **multiple platform.** so basically you have more coverage with mere changes.

Comment: To add to this, in my experience the selectors that are created by record and playback tools are extremely fragile. If there is a chance the pages in question will go through minor UI tweaks (or snippets of the code are auto generated,) then the record and playback tool may require lots of re-recording around that, whereas a well-formed selector by an engineer should be tolerant to that.

Comment: @PandaMagnus :  I agree ! thanks for the valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience and the experience of all the professionals I worked with and spoken with it is much better to work with **Code/script based** tools like Selenium.
The most "problem" in this approach - you will need engineers with good coding skills to perform this job while to make automation with **Record and Play** tools you can do with less professional staff.

Answer (score -1):

if you go for ranorex you'll get both:

Selenium WebDriver is built into the Ranorex core

[Here](https://www.ranorex.com/ranorex-vs-selenium/) you can find a list, comparing selenium vs. ranorex